# Why is the function in this Parking Lot simulator program not running/producing output

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, global-variables, local-variables

I am wondering what is wrong with this code? what steps can I take to make the function and its output run? Should the variables be placed inside the function, or is there something wrong with my loops? The goal is for the function to take the 4 inputs, and then produce the output I have specified. I am getting issues with the scope of the variables. When it runs like this, I get no output. Where should I place the variables in order for them to be modified and then printed as I want them to?

```
#Question 1: (RUNS SOMEWHAT, SEEMS BEST) 
#refer to the file Assignment 1 Q1 test for an alt version 
#We are writing a function called PLSimulation, which takes 4 integers as a parameters
#param 1 (x) = minimum number of cars that can park in 1 hour 
#param 2 (y) = max # than can park in 1 hour
#param 3 (z)= max that can leave in 1 hour
#param 4 (h) = # of hours to run 
# variable (totalarrived) = total # of arrived cars
# variable(totalLeft) = total # of cars that left
#total_parked_cars = how many cars have park across the entire period of time
#cars_waiting_to_park = how many are in the queue
#arrival_rate = hourly arrival rate (as a % of how many can park)
#departure_rate= hourly departure rate(as a % of how many can leave)
#the function PLSsimulation indicates how many came in, how many came out
#as well as how many are waiting 
import random 
x=input("Enter the minimum number of cars that can park in an hour: ")
y=input("Enter the maximum number of cars that can park in an hour: ")
z=input("Enter the maximum number of cars that can leave in an hour: ")
h=input("How many hours do you want the simulation to run for?: ")
#int forms of inputs for use in PLSimulation 
int_x=int(x)
int_y = int(y)
int_z = int(z)
int_h=int(h)
total_parked_cars= 0
cars_waiting_to_park = 0 
totalarrived=0
totalLeft=0
arrival_rate= (totalarrived/(int_h*int_y))
departure_rate= (totalLeft/(int_h*int_z))
#Goal 1: During the course of the function, the program should do h-1, until h==0, then break 
#This will be create a loop that runs the program until there are no more hours left
def PLSimulation(int_x,int_y,int_z,int_h):
    total_hours = h
    int_total_hours = int(total_hours)
    while(int_total_hours>0):
        #This while loop that goes from total_hours to 0 accomplishes goal 1
        #my aim is to loop the function of each hour, then subratcted from the total
        #until 0 is hit
        for hour in range(0,int_h+1): 
        #This part generates the number of cars ready to arrive/leave per hour:
               arrived_in_the_hour= random.randrange(int_x,int_y+1)
               left_in_the_hour = random.randrange(0,int_z+1)
               #This part adds the cars which arrived/subtracts the cars which left to the total arrived: 
               totalarrived += arrived_in_the_hour
               totalarrived -= left_in_the_hour
                #This part adds the cars which left/subtracts the cars which arrived to the total left: 
               totalLeft += left_in_the_hour
               totalLeft -= arrived_in_the_hour
            #adds the arrived in the hour to waiting to park/the queue every hour:
               cars_waiting_to_park+= arrived_in_the_hour
            #removes the cars that left from the queue:
               cars_waiting_to_park-= left_in_the_hour
            #adds the cars parked to the total parked:
               total_parked_cars+= cars_waiting_to_park
            #removes the now parked cars from the queue:
               cars_waiting_to_park -=total_parked_cars
                  
        int_total_hours += int_h-1 
     #here, when total_hours ==0 and the while loop ends, print the report
#call the function so that it runs 
PLSimulation(int_x,int_y,int_z,int_h)
print("The simulation is complete!\n The car arrival rate is: ", arrival_rate,
      "\nThe car departure rate is: ", departure_rate,
      "\nThe number of cars waiting to park is: ",cars_waiting_to_park)
```

Comment: You might want to add a language tag to your question. Also taking the [tour] and reading through [ask] might improve your chances of getting the answer you want.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.